# HTTP Response-> Getting an exact number of bytes, then closing the connection

Tags: php, http

I am running into a silly problem: I need to get a certain number of bytes, then close the connection. I've found I can extract the "Content Length" from the header, and use the length to determine just how many more bytes I should get before severing the connection. However, it appears I have made a mistake. It is only getting 40 bytes, instead of 2428 (as it should). Perhaps I am not using fgets() correctly?

Here is the code:

```
private static function Send($URL, $Data) {
            $server = parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_HOST);
            $port = parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_PORT);

            // If the parsing the port information fails, we will assume it's on a default port.
            // As such, we'll set the port in the switch below.
            if($port == null) {
                switch(parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) {
                    case "HTTP":
                        $port = 80;
                        break;
                    case "HTTPS":
                        $port = 443;
                        break;

                }
            }

            // Check if we are using a proxy (debug configuration typically).
            if(\HTTP\HTTPRequests::ProxyEnabled) {
                $server = \HTTP\HTTPRequests::ProxyServer;
                $port = \HTTP\HTTPRequests::ProxyPort;
            }



            // Open a connection to the server.
            $connection = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr);
            if (!$connection) {
                die("OMG Ponies!");
            }
            echo "===========================================================<BR>";
            echo "Connection Open<BR>";
            echo "The Time is " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
            echo "Sending Request<BR>";

            fwrite($connection, $Data);

            echo "Request Sent.";
            echo "The Time is " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
            $responseheader = "";
            $responsebody = "";


            /*
            \HTTP\HTTPRequests::$start = NULL;
            \HTTP\HTTPRequests::$timeout = 10;

            // @todo: Rewrite this. Should keep checking for '/r/n/r/n', then check for a content length header. If found, keep grabbing bytes, then close. If not, then close immediately.
            while(!\HTTP\HTTPRequests::safe_feof($connection, \HTTP\HTTPRequests::$start) && (microtime(true) - \HTTP\HTTPRequests::$start) < \HTTP\HTTPRequests::$timeout)
            {
                $response .= fgets($connection);
            }
            */
            echo "Getting Response<BR>";
            echo "The Time is " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
            while(!feof($connection) && !(strlen(strstr($responseheader,"\r\n\r\n"))>0)) {
                $responseheader .= fgets($connection);
            }

            echo "The Header is fully received at " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
            echo "Header (raw):" . "<BR>";
            echo "/////////////////////////////////////////////<BR>";
            echo $responseheader . "<BR>";
            echo "/////////////////////////////////////////////<BR>";

            if((strlen(strstr($responseheader,"Content-Length:"))>0)) {
                $contentlength = ((int)(\Extract\Extract::GetContentLength($responseheader)));
                //for($i = 0; $i < $contentlength; $i++) {
                    $responsebody .= fgets($connection, $contentlength);
                //}
                echo "The Body is fully received at " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
                echo "Body (raw):" . "<BR>";
                echo "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}<BR>";
                echo $responsebody . "<BR>";
                echo "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}<BR>";
                echo "<B>!Content length is " . strlen($responsebody) . ". It should be " . $contentlength . "!</B><BR>";
            }

            echo "Response Received.<BR>";
            echo "The Time is " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
            fclose($connection);

            echo "Connection Closed.<BR>";
            echo "The Time is " . date("H:i:su", time()) . "<BR>";
            echo "Exiting Send() method.<BR>";
            echo "===========================================================<BR>";
            echo "<BR>";

            return $responseheader . $responsebody;
        }
```

And here is the output:

```
===========================================================
Connection Open
The Time is 15:57:29000000
Sending Request
Request Sent.The Time is 15:57:29000000
Getting Response
The Time is 15:57:29000000
The Header is fully received at 15:57:29000000
Header (raw):
/////////////////////////////////////////////
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 19:57:18 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.14 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_wsgi/2.0 Python/2.5.2 mod_perl/2.0.3 Perl/v5.8.8 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.14 DAV: 1, 2, 3, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule DAV: extended-mkcol, calendar-proxy, bind, addressbook, calendar-auto-schedule Content-Location: /davical/caldav.php/rwr26/home/ ETag: "8378ead7e628deafd91ec99dc180ad74" X-DAViCal-Version: DAViCal/0.9.9; DB/1.2.9 Content-Length: 2428 Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8" 
/////////////////////////////////////////////
The Body is fully received at 15:57:29000000
Body (raw):
{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
!Content length is 40. It should be 2428!
Response Received.
The Time is 15:57:29000000
Connection Closed.
The Time is 15:57:29000000
Exiting Send() method.
===========================================================
```

Why am I doing it this way? Apparently, I was running into some sort of a timeout error, which makes each connection stay open for 30 seconds (yes, 30 whole seconds). So I wrote this code to get the exact number of bytes, then close. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what's going on with your HTTP requests. What you're doing doesn't exactly follow the standards of the HTTP protocol, and from what it sounds like, all of this work is just so you can work around a problem (30 second connection) not truly solve it. Perhaps you'd be better off asking a question about your original problem, not your workaround.

Comment: what is the hidden 40 characters - are they really all 'spaces' or hidden tags? 207 response is an XML response - aka tags - check the source code and post might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the content line "$responsebody .= fgets($connection, $contentlength);" to "$responsebody .= stream_get_line($connection, $contentlength);". Thing is wicked fast now, and works.